# SQL Percentage of each values from sum of row

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

I'm trying to get the percentage of each values from this query. I know this question might be a duplicate, but I cannot manage to make it work.

```
SELECT SUM(distance) AS SUM_DISTANCE FROM table1 GROUP BY type
```

It gives me this:

```
+------------------+
|   SUM_DISTANCE   |
+------------------+
| 60159.7965819000 |
|   289.0123500000 |
| 34660.5349672000 |
+------------------+
```

What I want to get is this:

```
+-----------------+
| PercentDistance |
+-----------------+
|           63,25 |
|            0,30 |
|           36,44 |
+-----------------+
```

Here is my attempt:

```
WITH Total AS
    (SELECT SUM(distance) AS SUM_DISTANCE FROM table GROUP BY type)
select
    (total.SUM_DISTANCE / sum(distance)) * 100 AS PercentDistance
FROM table1, Total
GROUP BY Total.SUM_DISTANCE;
```

This is the result of my attempt:

```
+-----------------+
| PercentDistance |
+-----------------+
|        0.001300 |
|        0.159900 |
|        0.277600 |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT CAST(100 * SUM(distance) / SUM(SUM(distance)) OVER () AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS percentage
FROM table1
GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUM(distance) / (SELECT SUM(distance) FROM table1) AS SUM_DISTANCE
FROM table1
GROUP BY type
```